# Trouble receiving Pythagoras OTA

Tags: google-project-tango

A few system updates ago I had trouble receiving the OTA for the Tango.  It appears that a similar problem has occurred again.

My Tango core has successfully updated to the Pythagoras revision, but my kernel version still reads build KOT49H.150505.  I have tried the obvious things such as clicking on "check for updates" in the "About tablet" settings menu, but I still get that my system is up to date.

On the developer release notes it says that the kernel build should be KOT49H.150609.

A couple of questions, has anyone successfully downloaded the latest OTA?  How can I get my tablet to download this new kernel version?

I am worried about this mismatch between tango core and OTA since last time it rendered the tango basically unusable.  This time around things seem to be relatively stable, but I am worried that perhaps there might be performance degradation.

Comment: Project Tango apparently has trouble in synchronizing system and app updates. Besides counseling patience, I would recommend turning off automatic Play Store updates and update manually when the system update arrives.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did indeed get the update the other day, and I have turned off auto-update.